# $\mid-1+2-3+4-5+6-7+10-11+...+(p_{k}-1)-p_{k}\mid=k$? Where $p_{k}$ is the $k$-th prime.

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I'm not sure if it's a ***Telescoping series*** but I tried the generating rule to prove and test the series but I'm not getting any insight and I got stuck.

Here are few **Examples**:

$$\mid-1+2-3+4-5+6-7\mid=4$$ $7$ is the $4$-th prime.
$$\mid-1+2-3+4-5+6-7+10-11\mid=5$$ $11$ is the $5$-th prime.
$$\mid-1+2-3+4-5+6-7+10-11+12-13+16-17+18-19\mid=8$$
$19$ is the $8$-th prime and so on.

Any proof and insight would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your sum consists of the $k$ summands $(p_1-1)-p_1$, $(p_2-1)-p_2$, ..., $(p_k-1)-p_k$ and every summand equals $-1$, so their sum is $-k$.

Comment: Thanks, how did I miss to see that! @Dreipunkt